# When can we end up on the same seat?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

You and your friend  sit at the  opposite side of  a round table with 10 seats. You  play a seat moving game by  throwing **in turn** three dices of blue, green and red simultaneously. $(x, y, z)$  represent the outcome of each throw.

**Rules**:

Blue: Move CW if $x$ is even, otherwise CCW.

Green: Move to the $y^{th}$ seat(s) next to you.

Red:  Reset back to original seat if $z$ is 1.

**Question**:

On average after how many throws both of you will sit on the same chair?

Comment: Do you and your friend alternate throws, or are you the only one to roll the dice?  What have you done on this problem so far?

Comment: We throw in turn. This is my original question. Since there are too nany scenarios, it is difficult to draw a clear picture, even though there is no memory in the game, Markov transition matrix does not seem to apply. I got stuck here.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks! I will study the reference - great to learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be modelled as finite-state, [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).
Let us number the chairs from $0$ to $9$, with you originally in chair $0$ and your friend in chair $5$.  A state is of the form $(y, f, t)$ where $y$ is the number of the chair you are sitting in, $f$ is the number of the chair your friend is sitting in, and $t$ indicates whose turn it is, say $0$ if it your turn, and $1$ if it is your friend's turn.  The initial state is $(0,5,0)$.

All states with $y\neq f$ are transient, and we collapse all the states with $y=f$ into a single absorbing state.  That gives $180$ transient states and one absorbing state, so we have to deal with a $180\times180$ matrix, and hand-calculation is impossible.  It shouldn't be difficult to do this with a computer program, though.  In each state, there are $216$ rolls of the dice, but they have essentially the same effect in every each state, depending on whose turn it is.  You need to number the states so that you can relate them to the matrix.

**EDIT**

Sorry. I misunderstood what you said about there being no memory.  Of course you are right.  It's just a matter of figuring out what the states are.  Then you can compute the average time to absorption in the usual way.